# Trying to avoid duplication in Oracle query with table alias causing "missing right parenthesis" error

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I am trying to write a query that assembles a list of ID numbers from two tables.

The first part of the query selects employee ID numbers that start with 'B' and were created after January 1, 2020 from a table containing the master list of IDs. The second part of the query looks at another table that holds team IDs (which are composed of two or more employee IDs) - basically I want to select any team ID that contains an employee ID that meets the criteria in the first query.

I have the below code working and it returns the proper data:

```
SELECT 
    emp_id AS id
FROM 
    emp_master_view 
WHERE 
    emp_id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.team_id AS id
    FROM team_master_view t
    WHERE t.emp_id IN
    (
        SELECT emp_id
        FROM emp_master_view
        WHERE SUBSTR(emp_id, 1, 1) IN ('B')
        AND crt_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    )
)
UNION SELECT emp_id AS id
FROM emp_master_view
WHERE SUBSTR(emp_id, 1, 1) IN ('B')
AND crt_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

However, I hate the duplication I need to use with the union select statement...I tried using a table alias like this:

```
SELECT 
    emp_id
FROM 
    emp_master_view 
WHERE 
    emp_id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.team_id AS emp_id
    FROM team_master_view t
    WHERE team_id IN
    (
        SELECT emp_id
        FROM emp_master_view
        WHERE SUBSTR(emp_id, 1, 1) IN ('B')
        AND crt_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    ) emp
)
UNION SELECT emp_id
FROM emp
```

...but this causes a "missing right parenthesis" error. I know I'm making some dumb mistake but I've tried a number of variations and can't get it working without duplicating the select entirely, so I'm waving the white flag. Can anyone point out the proper way to use a table alias in this case?

*Edit*

Sample data would be as follows:

`emp_master_view` contains the master list for every ID number, including teams:

```
EMP_MASTER_VIEW
+--------+------------+
| emp_id |  crt_date  |
+--------+------------+
| B56    | 2019-11-02 |
| B99    | 2020-03-02 |
| S34    | 2020-03-02 |
| RZF    | 2020-04-01 |
| RQR    | 2020-04-01 |
+--------+------------+
```

`team_master_view` contains only team IDs and there is a row for every individual employee in the team:

```
TEAM_MASTER_VIEW
+---------+--------+
| team_id | emp_id |
+---------+--------+
| RZF     | B99    |
| RZF     | B56    |
| RQR     | B56    |
| RQR     | S34    |
+---------+--------+
```

Desired results - pull out all of the IDs in the `emp_master_view` that meet the criteria and ALSO select all the team IDs from `team_master_view` where that team ID contains one of the employee IDs selected in the first part of the query.

Given the above tables, it would select B99 from `emp_master_view` as it's the only code that meets both criteria (starts with 'B' and created after Jan 1 2020). It would also select RZF from the `team_master_view` because that team ID contains B99. The end result set would be two rows:

```
B99
RZF
```

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement would help.

Comment: replace `UNION SELECT emp_id FROM emp` with  `UNION ( SELECT emp_id FROM emp )`

Comment: no, that's not the case @zealous

Comment: @GordonLinoff added some more detail, hope that helps...

Comment: @zealous same error using your suggestion

Comment: @Jim, what is the full version of oracle?

Comment: @Slkrasnodar 11g enterprise edition release 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use the same query more than once, you could use the **WITH** clause for **subquery factoring**:

```
with data as
(
    SELECT emp_id AS id
    FROM emp_master_view
    WHERE SUBSTR(emp_id, 1, 1) IN ('B')
    AND crt_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
)
SELECT 
    emp_id AS id
FROM 
    emp_master_view 
WHERE 
    emp_id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.team_id AS id
    FROM team_master_view t
    WHERE t.emp_id IN
    (
        SELECT emp_id
        FROM data)
)
UNION 
select emp_id from data;
```

**Update:**

After you posted your table data and requirement, it looks like a simple **JOIN** between the two tables:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, 
       t.team_id
FROM
    emp_master_view e
    JOIN team_master_view t 
    ON e.emp_id = t.emp_id
WHERE
    e.emp_id LIKE 'B%'
    AND e.crt_date >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: See the edits I made, they explain what I'm after in more detail. As mentioned, the first query I posted is working properly, I'm just trying to see if there's a way I can eliminate the duplication (the same query being used for the UNION as in the WHERE clause of the other query) - thought using an alias would allow me to refer back to the statement eliminating the duped code

Comment: @Jim See the edited answer, I updated it after you updated your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!! As you can tell, SQL/Oracle is not my expertise so thanks for teaching me a new clause to use!

Comment: @Jim See the update section, I think you are over complicating your query, it could be done using a simple JOIN.

Comment: geez you're right, was so head down in working on the code that was given to me I didn't even see that. Even better, thank you!

Comment: Actually the JOIN version doesn't work because it doesn't pull the team ID (it gives me B99 twice, not B99 and RZF) - but I'll play around with it, I'm sure I can get there in a simpler statement!

Comment: @Jim Based on your sample data, it will give you `B99` emp_id and `RZF` team_id. See the query in the update and try to play around a bit and you will get a better hold of it.

Comment: That looks better - I really appreciate the help, any day I walk away learning something is a good day!